# nested looping prints strange results

Tags: rust

Was trying to check a 2d vector and noticed some weird behavior that I haven't been able to find a explanation for.

```
fn main() {
    let mut main_loop = vec![];
    let mut x = 0;
    let board_x = 10;
    let mut y = 0;
    let board_y = 10;

    while y < board_y {
        let mut row = vec![];
        while x < board_x {
            let v = random::<bool>();
            println!("x:{}", x);
            row.push(v);
            x = x + 1;
        }
        println!("y:{}", y);
        main_loop.push(row);
        y = y + 1;
    }
}
```

This only prints

```
x:0
x:1
x:2
x:3
x:4
x:5
x:6
x:7
x:8
x:9
y:0
y:1
y:2
y:3
y:4
y:5
y:6
y:7
y:8
y:9
```

Shouldn't this be printing out x:1 - x:10 10 times? Also what was even stranger was that when I looped back over the vectors using a nested for loops for each row, it counted out 60 indexes before exiting out. What am I missing?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=5f3af2a3d532ece1d8684bd1fae522ed for exemple

Comment: Please use rustfmt to format your code properly next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't this be printing out x:1 - x:10 10 times?

Why would it?  You never set `x` back to zero after the inner loop is done.

Besides which, this sort of iteration should be done with a `for` loop:

```
for x in 0..10 { ... }
```

> [...] when I looped back over the vectors using a nested for loops for each row, it counted out 60 indexes before exiting out.

I don't know; you didn't post that code, and I can't see any reason it would do that.